# Navigating using Polaris Link in Shopify Embedded App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, shopify, polaris

I am building a Shopify embedded app with Polaris and React with file-based routing and I'm trying to navigate to a page inside the app when I click on a Link inside a table. I tried several methods and none seem to work.

**PolarisProvider.jsx**

````
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { AppProvider } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { useNavigate } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import translations from '@shopify/polaris/locales/en.json';
import '@shopify/polaris/build/esm/styles.css';

const AppBridgeLink = ({ url, children, external, ...rest }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    navigate(url);
  }, [url]);

  const IS_EXTERNAL_LINK_REGEX = /^(?:[a-z][a-z\d+.-]*:|\/\/)/;

  if (external || IS_EXTERNAL_LINK_REGEX.test(url)) {
    return (
      <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={url} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <a onClick={handleClick} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};

AppBridgeLink.propTypes = {
  url: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.element,
  external: PropTypes.bool,
};

/**
 * Sets up the AppProvider from Polaris.
 * @desc PolarisProvider passes a custom link component to Polaris.
 * The Link component handles navigation within an embedded app.
 * Prefer using this vs any other method such as an anchor.
 * Use it by importing Link from Polaris, e.g:
 *
 * ```
 * import {Link} from '@shopify/polaris'
 *
 * function MyComponent() {
 *  return (
 *    <div><Link url="/tab2">Tab 2</Link></div>
 *  )
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * PolarisProvider also passes translations to Polaris.
 *
 */
const PolarisProvider = ({ children }) => 
  <AppProvider i18n={translations} linkComponent={AppBridgeLink}>
    {children}
  </AppProvider>;

PolarisProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element,
};

export default PolarisProvider;
````

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavigationMenu } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';

import Routes from './Routes';
import {
  AppBridgeProvider,
  QueryProvider,
  PolarisProvider,
} from './components';

export default function App() {
  // Any .tsx or .jsx files in /pages will become a route
  // See documentation for <Routes /> for more info
  const pages = import.meta.globEager('./pages/**/!(*.test.[jt]sx)*.([jt]sx)');

  return (
    <PolarisProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppBridgeProvider>
          <QueryProvider>
            <NavigationMenu
              navigationLinks={[
                {
                  label: 'Products',
                  destination: '/',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Catalogues',
                  destination: '/catalogues/main',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Tags',
                  destination: '/tags/tags',
                },
              ]}
              matcher={(link, location) => link.destination === location.pathname}
            />
            <Routes pages={pages} />
          </QueryProvider>
        </AppBridgeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </PolarisProvider>
  );
}
```

**Routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes as ReactRouterRoutes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * File-based routing.
 * @desc File-based routing that uses React Router under the hood.
 * To create a new route create a new .jsx file in `/pages` with a default export.
 *
 * Some examples:
 * * `/pages/ProductsHome/ProductsHome.jsx` matches `/`
 * * `/pages/blog/[id].jsx` matches `/blog/123`
 * * `/pages/[...catchAll].jsx` matches any URL not explicitly matched
 *
 * @param {object} pages value of import.meta.globEager(). See https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import
 *
 * @return {Routes} `<Routes/>` from React Router, with a `<Route/>` for each file in `pages`
 */
const Routes = ({ pages }) => {
  const routes = useRoutes(pages);
  const routeComponents = routes.map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
  ));

  const NotFound = routes.find(({ path }) => path === '/notFound').component;

  return (
    <ReactRouterRoutes>
      {routeComponents}
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </ReactRouterRoutes>
  );
};

function useRoutes(pages) {
  const routes = Object.keys(pages)
    .map((key) => {
      let path = key
        .replace('./pages', '')
        .replace(/\.(t|j)sx?$/, '')
        /**
         * Replace /ProductsHome/ProductsHome with /
         */
        .replace(/\/ProductsHome\/ProductsHome$/i, '/')
        /**
         * Only lowercase the first letter. This allows the developer to use camelCase
         * dynamic paths while ensuring their standard routes are normalized to lowercase.
         */
        .replace(/\b[A-Z]/, (firstLetter) => firstLetter.toLowerCase())
        /**
         * Convert /[handle].jsx and /[...handle].jsx to /:handle.jsx for react-router-dom
         */
        .replace(/\[(?:[.]{3})?(\w+?)\]/g, (_match, param) => `:${param}`);

      if (path.endsWith('/') && path !== '/') {
        path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
      }

      if (!pages[key].default) {
        console.warn(`${key} doesn't export a default React component`);
      }

      return {
        path,
        component: pages[key].default,
      };
    })
    .filter((route) => route.component);

  return routes;
}

Routes.propTypes = {
  pages: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Routes;
```

This is the Link I'm using inside of the table.

```
<Link to={`/catalogues/details/${value}`}>{value}</Link>;
```

Using this setup, clicking the link doesn't do anything. I even put a console.log inside of the handleClick function and nothing gets logged as if it is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use the `Link` component.

To navigate inside the app you can use

```
     <Link onClick={() => {
            const url = `/products/${id}`; // for example to go to a /products/id page
            redirect.dispatch(Redirect.Action.APP, url);
      }}>
            <Text as="p" alignment="center" variant="bodyMd" fontWeight="bold">{product.title}</Text>
      </Link>
```

That lets you add some custom code before being redirected, or the more simple

```
  <Link url={"/products/2"} external={false}>{product.title}</Link>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I use this code and click the link. The `handleClick` function inside PolarisProvider.jsx doesn't even get called. I checked the condition to see if it is instantiating it as an internal link and it is so that isn't the problem. I also tried adding an event inside the `handleClick` function and doing `event.preventDefault()` but that also did nothing. When I put an `onClick` inside the Link component and use `navigate` from react-router inside it navigates to the correct page but then when I click the navigation items inside the menu the URL changes but the view doesn't.

Comment: @VladanMikic is the link inside some component? Sometimes inside Tables or similar it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the link is inside a Polaris IndexTable component. I followed the [example](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/tables/index-table) from the Polaris docs.

Comment: @VladanMikic Ah yes, I had the same problem. The issue is the not the Link component but that somehow the table is capturing the clicke event. Try to update polaris.